# What is making spring boot console colorful?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When I start my own spring boot with 2.2.2 release, it is only white text. When I see very similar examples with the same spring boot version, they have colored console output. What is the reason? And where is it defined?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: find application.properties file in your project and set spring.output.ansi.enabled = always

Comment: or use the very powerful (and very unfortunately named) "grep console" extension of IntelliJ IDEA, to have anything colored the way you like, not just spring boot output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be done in your property file. here is an exemple.

```
   logging:
      level:
        root: INFO
      pattern:
        console: "%black(%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}) ===== %highlight(%-5level) ===== [%blue(%thread)] ===== %yellow(%logger{36}.%M):%L ===== %msg%n%throwable"
```

Please do also check spring docs for more about logging https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-logging.html